# Linux Redirections; Possible to Toggle Between Redirects?

Tags: linux, redirect

I want to be able to toggle between redirects.  ie:

Redirect #1 would be:
Don't redirect to stdout, Redirect the output to a file.

Redirect #2 would be:
Don't redirect to file... rather redirect to stdout

Is it possible to do this at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it goes for bash (for C it would be pretty the same):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo begin experiment

exec 3>&1-

exec > to_file

echo this goes to file
echo another line to file

exec 1>&3-

echo this goes again to stdout
```

Comment: One more redirect example (http://www.ashep.org/2010/perenapravleniya-v-bash-pri-pomoshhi-exec) but in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from inside a bash script (so it is not the caller to decide) with

exec >file

or

exec >$(tty)

Answer (score 0):

As a quasi-medieval alternative, you could install [Konsole](http://konsole.kde.org/) or some other terminal that let's you save the output to a file. You can save the output at any point while an application is running (runtime) on your terminal.

On Konsole you would click on: **Scrollback > Save Output**

You didn't specifically said you were looking for a programming solution, so I believe the idea is valid.